# Get all fields in WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using an oracle database. For this database I have to code up a filter. I am doing the filtering within the `WHERE` sql clause.

However, if the filter is not intact I would like to set the `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name = '*'`. This does not work. Any recommedations how to set the `WHERE clause` to all `names` WITHOUT leaving it out?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: WHERE (1 = 1) AND (other)

Comment: @realnumber3012 Thx for your answer! How would this goe with my example?

Comment: if you use params in query try this solution WHERE (1 = 1) AND (:name IS NULL OR Name = :name) , if you don't wont pass param you get all names

Comment: You have to use `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name like '%'`

Comment: @Jens Thx for your answer! Would you be so kind to explain why this works in your answer?

Comment: you can use simply as SELECT distinct name FROM Person

Comment: @Hardik Yes true. But the filtering works with a where clause!

Comment: @Vivien this works, because the `%` sign selects everything. So you just have to replace `*` with it.

Comment: @Vivien in SQL the wildcard is `%` not the asterix. and like is the operator which enables wildcard search. I add the Comment as answer. Feel free to upvote/accept it, of it helps you.

Comment: but if you want only name then why want to filter if you are writing that fetch distict name OR where name condition will work the samne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name like '%'`

In `SQL` the wildcard is `%` not the `asterix`. and like is the operator which enables wildcard search.

Comment: `NULL` names will be excluded, so technically, the answer is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

I interpret 'how to set the `WHERE` clause to all `names` WITHOUT leaving it out' as 'I want the fieldname `Name` to appear in the `WHERE` clause but I want all  records.

```
... WHERE Name like '%' or Name is null
```

would return all rows (I am quite sure that `like '%'` also matches the empty string)

Coding of your filter should dynamically exclude or include the fields selected. In other words: Create the query string dynamically, similar to this

```
whereClause = '1=1';
foreach (filter in filterConditions) {
  if (!filter.IsEmpty) {
    whereClause += ' AND '+filter.SQLExpression
  }
}
```

Sorry, I am not familiar with Java, but I hope you do get the point. Of course, you should still introduce parameters (coded in the `filter.SQLExpression`) instead of directly coding the filter value into the SQLExpression.

Answer (score 0):

If `Name` column has to be sole criteria for searching in the table, try it this way :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person 
WHERE Name IN ( select distinct Name --fetch distinct names 
                from Person ) --and then search through it
```